# Pygame sprite disappearing with layeredUpdates at a certain Y coordinate

Tags: python, pygame

I am making this game with pygame, and have got a `player` sprite drawn with layeredUpdates. The `_layer` for the player is 1, and for some reason, when he gets to a certain point on the y coordinate, he just disappears. The `ground` sprite has a `_layer` of 2, so the `player` sprite should always be on top. It's odd that he just disappears at a certain y coordinate.

main.py:

```
import pygame
from sprites import *
from settings import *
from os import path

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        pygame.key.set_repeat(500, 100)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        main_folder = path.dirname(__file__)
        img_dir = path.join(main_folder, 'img')
        self.map_data = []
        with open(path.join(main_folder, 'map.txt'), 'rt') as f:
            for line in f:
                self.map_data.append(line)
        self.spritesheet = Spritesheet(path.join(img_dir, SPRITESHEET))

    def new(self):
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.grounds = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map_data):
            for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
                Ground(self, col, row)
                if tile == 'a':
                    Block(self, col, row)
                if tile == 'P':
                    self.player = Player(self, col, row)


    def run(self):
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    self.player.move(0,-1)
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    self.player.move(-1,0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    self.player.move(0,1)
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    self.player.move(1,0)


    def update(self):
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)
        self.all_sprites.update()
        self.clock.tick(FPS)

    def draw(self):
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.update()

g = Game()
while True:
    g.new()
    g.run()
```

sprites.py

```
import pygame
from settings import *

class Spritesheet:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        image.blit(self.spritesheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(0,32,32,32)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dir = 'UP'
        self._layer = PLAYER_LAYER

    def move(self, x_change, y_change):
        if x_change > 0:
            self.dir = 'RIGHT'
        if x_change < 0:
            self.dir = 'LEFT'
        if y_change > 0:
            self.dir = 'DOWN'
        if y_change < 0:
            self.dir = 'UP'

        if not self.collide(x_change, y_change):
            self.x += x_change
            self.y += y_change

    def collide(self, x_change, y_change):
        for block in self.game.blocks:
            if block.x == self.x + x_change and block.y == self.y + y_change and block.collidable:
                return True
        return False

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x = self.x * SCALE
        self.rect.y = self.y * SCALE

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y, collidable=True, groups=None):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups or (game.all_sprites, game.blocks))
        self.game = game
        self.image = pygame.Surface((SCALE, SCALE))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.collidable = collidable

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x = self.x * SCALE
        self.rect.y = self.y * SCALE

class Ground(Block):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y, collidable=False, groups=None):
        Block.__init__(self, game, x, y, collidable, groups or (game.all_sprites, game.grounds))
        self.image = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(0, 0, 32, 32)
        self._layer = GROUND_LAYER
```

settings.py:

```
WIN_WIDTH = 640
WIN_HEIGHT = 480

SPRITESHEET = 'sheet.png'

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)

TITLE = 'Pykemon'
SCALE = 32
FPS = 60

PLAYER_LAYER = 1
TREE_LAYER = 2
GROUND_LAYER = 3
```

map.txt:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
a..................a
a..................a
a..................a
a..................a
a..................a
a..................a
a..................a
a..................a
a....P.............a
a..................a
a..................a
a..................a
a..................a
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Thanks.

Comment: Trying to recreate it, could you post the rest of your code

Comment: @TheBigKahuna Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layers have to be in ascending order:

```py
PLAYER_LAYER = 3
TREE_LAYER = 2
GROUND_LAYER = 1
```

When a sprite is in layered group ([`pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates)) then the layer can be changed by [`switch_layer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.switch_layer):

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        # [...]        

        game.all_sprites.change_layer(self, PLAYER_LAYER)
```

```py
class Ground(Block):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y, collidable=False, groups=None):
        Block.__init__(self, game, x, y, collidable, groups or (game.all_sprites, game.grounds))
        self.image = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(0, 0, 32, 32)

        game.all_sprites.change_layer(self, GROUND_LAYER)
```

Note, changing the `_layer` attribute does not magically change the layer of the sprite. The `_layer` attribute has to be set before the sprite is add to the group. Thus you have to set the layer attribute **before** the `super()` calls:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):

        self._layer = PLAYER_LAYER

        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
```

```py
class Ground(Block):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y, collidable=False, groups=None):

        self._layer = GROUND_LAYER

        Block.__init__(self, game, x, y, collidable, groups or (game.all_sprites, game.grounds))
        self.image = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(0, 0, 32, 32)
```

Alternatively a layer in a group is created, if a `layer` keyword argument is passed to [`add()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.add). While the following works (if `self` is not in `game.all_sprites` before):

```py
game.all_sprites.add(self, layer=PLAYER_LAYER)
```

Comment: Actually the attribute **is** `_layer`, not layer. The pygame docs were wrong and I just got them corrected today. If you use the proper `_layer` attribute, just assigning a value to it in the sprite is totally sufficient to move it to whichever layer the number you assign is. There is no 'creating' a layer. It just goes though the sprites by order of whatever the `_layer` attribute indicates. In my code I move them up and down all the time just by assigning to the `_layer` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Your GROUND_LAYER  is 3 and your PLAYER_LAYER is 1. Lower numbered layers are under higher numbered layers, so the player will be hidden by the ground.

You position the ground tiles based on data from a file 'map.txt'. I do not know what that is but I am guessing that it is when the player goes to what you intend to be over one of those ground tiles,  it is actually going under it. Or maybe it is going under a tree.

Try reversing the order of your  PLAYER, TREE and GROUND layers.

```
PLAYER_LAYER = 3
TREE_LAYER = 2
GROUND_LAYER = 1
```

@Rabbid76 was correct about the layer ordering in his answer, though not about the `_layer` attribute or the way `_layer` works. No offense is intended by this @Rabbid76, the docs were actually wrong and I just had this corrected in the docs earlier today. The [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) now say "If the sprite you add has an attribute _layer then that layer will be used."

Also you can place a sprite at any level that you like purely by assigning the `_layer` attribute to any number. There is not actually a thing like creating a layer. LayeredUpdates just goes though the sprites by order of whatever the `_layer` attribute indicates. In my code I place sprites in a layer and move sprites up or down just by just assigning to the `_layer` attribute. It might appear that way if you are using the incorrect attribute name since you have to use the various methods that manipulate the layers for it to work without setting `_layer`.

Comment: No i would agree with @Rabbid76, i was running the code and printing `all_sprites.layers()` and it only returned `[0]`. after finding a solution similar to @Rabbid76s, it would print all the layers. Also you dont know what map.txt is,  they showed you what is was at the very bottom